# What does it mean by "odds that an event will occur is $2$ to $3$"?

Tags: probability

> In a swimming race, the odds that $A$ will win are 2 to 3 and the odds that $B$ will win are 1 to 4 Find the probability $p$ and the odds that $A$ or $B$ wins the race.

What does it mean by odds that an event will occur is $2$ to $3$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds: "In simplest terms, 6 to 1 odds means if you bet a dollar (the "1" in the expression), and you win you get paid six dollars (the "6" in the expression), or 6 x 1. If you bet two dollars you would be paid twelve dollars, or 6 x 2. If you bet three dollars and win, you would be paid eighteen dollars, or 6 x 3. If you bet one hundred dollars and win you would be paid six hundred dollars, or 6 x 100. If you lose any of those bets you would lose the dollar, or two dollars, or three dollars, or one hundred dollars."

Comment: @Antinous, why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Its a direct quote from Wikipedia so didn't think it merited presence as an answer tbh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *odds* are $2:3$ when the *probability* is $2/(2+3) = 2/5$.

**Edit** in response to comment.

Indeed odds are just ratios. $2:3$ is the same as $4:6$. I don't know why they came to be written that way, but I'm glad they are. If you think of them as fractions it's all too easy to confuse them with probabilities. Of course they can't be, since odds of $3:2$ make perfect sense but a probability of $3/2$ doesn't.

Odds are the usual way to express stakes in a bet. If the probability of an event is $2/5$ (as in your example) then it would be fair to stake $\$3$ against $\$2$ in a bet. You and your opponent each put the stake ($\$2$ or $\$3$) into the pot; the winner takes it all.

Comment: well, 2/(2+3)  ......................

Comment: @WillJagy Fixed thanks. You could have made the edit in about the same length of time it took to write the comment.

Comment: what is the secret behind this strange language choice (x to y)? why not just say $\frac{2}{5}$?

Comment: Ethan, yes, I remember doing that sort of thing years ago.  Sometimes people didn't like that

Comment: @yahoo.com $x/(x+y)$ is indeed $2/5$ for $x=2$ and $y=3$. This is the idea to use variables, like saying $x+y=1$, with some special example $x=2$, $y=-1$.

Comment: @user366312 This 3Blue1Brown 
video is apropos: [Why Bayes rule is nicer with odds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lG4VkPoG3ko).

Answer (score 1):

The odds for an event are $x$ to $y$ if the probability of that event is $x/(x+y)$.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition behind the notation $x:y$ is that there are $x$ unfavorable outcomes for every $y$ favorable outcomes. For example, the odds against spinning a black in European roulette are $19:18$, since there are $19$ red/green sections and $18$ black sections.

In other words, while a probability measures the ratio $\frac{\text{good}}{\text{total}}$, the odds against measure the ratio $\frac{\text{bad}}{\text{good}}$.

I do not know the history of this notation, but there is a reason for why we care about this ratio. If an event has odds of $x:y$ against, then it would be a fair bet to receive $x$ dollars if the event succeeds and $y$ dollars if the event fails. This is equivalent to receiving $x/y$ dollars for a success and losing $1$ dollar for a failure. That is, the odds against is the ratio of money won to money lost for a fair bet on that event.